# Ошибка при POST запросе к spotify API

Tags: java, rest, oauth

Не могу сделать POST запрос к spotify API на обмен ключа авторизации (это сделал) на токен. Вместо токена получаю `{"error":"invalid_client"}`.
Код метода с запросом:

```
private void makeRequest(){
    if (code == null) {
        return;
    }
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .setHeader("Authorization", encoded_ID_SECRET)
        .uri(URI.create("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"))
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("grant_type" +
            "=authorization_code&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri))
        .build();
    try {
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.body());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

`code`  - authorization_code распарсен вроде нормально.
`redirect_uri` - тот же, что и при получении authorization_code.
`encoded_ID_SECRET`  пара взята из дешборда в спотифай и закодирована base64. Взял `ID:SECRET` и онлайн кодировал.

Действовать пытался по [этому](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) гайду, а именно где про `Have your application request refresh and access tokens; Spotify returns access and refresh tokens`.
Предполагаю, что проблема в параметре хедера `Authorization`, но это не точно, и не понимаю как её исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед `encoded_ID_SECRET`не дописал `Basic`. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Пометь ответ как решение

Comment: @DeMmAge пока не могу, вечером помечу.